# Are all Microsoft Office updates uninstalled when removing Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I am just curious as to whether all the updates related to MS Office also get removed when performing a completed uninstall.

The reason I ask is I want to update Office 2007 and because it's a slightly slower system, I think the updates remain and may cause unnecessary slowness.

I did a quick Google search but couldn't find any specific answer to this.

Comment: Not my downvote, but what makes you think it would even be relevant to keep the updates installed when the updated software is uninstalled?

Comment: For some reason I was thinking it doesnt remove all updates and registry settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a spare virtual machine at hand with Office 2007 installed on it and fully updated, so I've decided to create a snapshot, uninstall Office and see what happens with Office updates.

Here's a screenshot before doing anything. Note that total number of updates is 59.

[image: Screenshot of "Installed Updates" window, with 59 updates installed in total. Many Office updates are visible.]

Here's the same window after uninstalling Office and rebooting the system, 20 updates installed.

[image: Screenshot of "Installed Updates" window, with 20 updates installed in total. No Office updates are visible.]

## 39 updates were removed automatically along with Office.

Comment: Thank you for this. I didnt get a chance to do a test on my own. so it does remove them, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

The updates still remain on your system. They are located in a sub-category as shown.
[View Installed Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBKzZ.png)

Comment: I haven't tested with any system (but will do soon) . I do also think that once we remove the software and try to install it again, the updates weill be needed. But my question is what happens to current updates/files, you screenshotted Visio (have you uninstalled the software and still see the updates, just to confirm)?